# What's the easiest way to peel frozen ginger?

Tags: food

Ginger root is an absolute pain to peel, especially when it's frozen which is the best way to keep it from getting moldy if you don't use it very often.

Other than a paring knife and a lot of patience is there a better way to peel ginger?

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the skin to thaw, but the interior is still frozen. That way, you can peel them without fear or getting too much/digging in. Putting it in a bowl of warm water for a few seconds gives a more uniform thaw than just setting it out.

And it's not that big a pain to do with a *sharp* paring knife, but you could try to use a dedicated vegetable peeler, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easier to peel while fresh with a vegetable peeler in my opinion. But for this problem:

- Do it while the skin is dry and the ginger has just a bit of give to it. Use a very sharp knife(a peeler will only work when the ginger is thawed).
- You could [grate it](http://www.wikihow.com/Prepare-Ginger-Root-For-Cooking#Storing_Ginger_Root_sub), but this is just a suggestion. A thing someone did because they had really big roots was grate the skin off.

> When you need to use the ginger, you can grate it while it's still
>   frozen. In fact, ginger is easier to work with while frozen as it is
>   less fibrous.

---

**Additional Info**

[WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Peel-Ginger-Root)

Comment: Good point.  I hadn't thought about peeling it before I froze it.